# Regex to match URLs starts with subdomain but not "www"

Tags: javascript, regex

I have set of possible URLs:

```
www.example.com
www.example.user.dev
subdomain.example.com
subdomain.example.user.dev
www.en.example.com
www.en.example.user.dev
subdomain.en.example.com
subdomain.en.example.user.dev
```

`subdomain` can be any word.
I need a regex that find all URLs that not starts with `www`, so the result set should be:

```
subdomain.example.com
subdomain.example.user.dev
subdomain.en.example.com
subdomain.en.example.user.dev
```

I have regex `/[a-z]+\.(en\.|)example\.(com|[a-z]+\.dev)/i` and i need to modify it to mathc only URLs which start not with `www`. Is it possible to solve with regex only or do i need to program some logic in code?

**UPD:**
The regex `/\b(?!www\b)[a-z]+\.(en\.|)example\.(com|[a-z]+\.dev)/i` works fine with URLs without `.en` part but fails on URLs that have `.en`.

Comment: If you have a list of *only* URLs like those, you can check each item with something like `!str.StartsWith("www.")` and do what you need later. A regex to check if a string does not start with `www.` is `^(?!www\.)`

Comment: It is possible way but i wish, if possible, do this check with regex

Comment: What type of regex are you using? (What language are you doing this in?)

Comment: It's javascript. I need to know what url is opened now to start or not some utility functions.

Comment: JS: `if (!/^www\./.test(str)) { ... }`. It seems to me you are overcomplicating things. You can use 2 small readable regexps rather than pack all into 1 incomprehensive pattern.

Comment: Nope. Also i have URLs like `subdomain.en.example.com/there/is/path/` and they have to be not matched with this regex (but will be matched by another).

Comment: The point is: I have a database with records that contain regex of page and (very simplified) a hint that should be show on that page after the page is loaded. Admin can add records to database and hints will be shown on another pages (with different regexes). I cannot modify the existing website code, i can only make a little JS that will be loaded with website, read settings and check if this page matches with any regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
^(?!www\.)((([a-z]{4,})|([a-z]{2}))\.(en\.|)example\.(com|[a-z]+\.dev))
```

Comment: Thank you, but it fails if `subdomain` is shorter than 4 symbols. My subdomains may have 2 or more symbols. If i change `{4,}` part to `{2,}` it starts to match `www.en.example.com` by `en.example.com` part. That's not expected behavior.

Comment: I edit my post with you requiremnts about subdomain can by two letters

Comment: I tested your answer and it seems a bit less compicated regex works like a charm: `^(?!www\.)(([a-z]{2,})\.(en\.|)renthome\.(ru|[a-z]+\.dev))` Thank you, you leaded me right way! I think you may edit your answer to my version to help people find it quicker if the need.

Comment: Or even simplier! `^(?!www\.)(([a-z]+)\.(en\.|)renthome\.(ru|[a-z]+\.dev))`